# Issues using DistanceTo(The Distance is not correct)

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to calculate the distance between my Geolocation point and a marker tracing a polyline between these two, but the problem is when i output the result and it gives me an enourmous distance(1.125405E7) instead of (For Example) 1,250m.

This is my code

```
//Gets the latitude & longitude of my Geolocation

 Location location = new Location("A");
                location.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                location.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

 //Gets the location of a marker/Polyline which i put using onMapLongCliclistener

                Location locationb = new Location("B");
                locationb.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
                locationb.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);

                //Calculates the distance between Geolocation/Marker

                double distance=locationb.distanceTo(location);

                String distancia = String.valueOf(distance);
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,distancia, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Any tip or solution?
Thank You Very Much!

Comment: You are setting latitude to `A`'s longitude twice and never set the latitude. Is that your real code or a mistake?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Fixed, still giving me a big distance

Comment: can you provide the actual coordinates of both locations and the appropriate distance result?

Comment: @PeppermintPaddy Check Answer, Already fixed it, Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

From you code line no 3 '*location.setLongitude(location.getLatitude());*' is wrong. You are setting longitude instead of latitude.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
 double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),new 
    LatLng(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude));
   String distanceC = String.valueOf(distance);
  txtDistancia.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(distanceC)+" "+"mts");
```